# convert CMSampleBuffer to m3u8 and save it to path?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cmsamplebuffer

Im using replaykit and broadcast upload extension to get devices screen recording.

```
override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
    switch sampleBufferType {
    case .video:
        break
    case .audioApp:
        break
    case .audioMic:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
```

With the function above I can get the sampleBuffer of the recording. How would I convert it to m3u8 and save it? It needs to be m3u8 because I will be hosting the file in localserver so it can be played real-time.

Comment: Help yourself by searching for 'CMSampleBuffer swift convert.'

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you, What a wonderful and helpful answer. Great to see all purple links, almost as if i've already searched those terms.